# Hibernate Cannot Instantiate ID Generator

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mariadb-10.4

Environment: Spring Boot 2.2.6
Starters: spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, *-thymeleaf, *-web, *-tomcat, *-test
Other dependencies: mariadb-java-client 2.6.0, spring-boot-devtools (MANAGED), lombok (MANAGED)
DB MariaDB: 10.4
Hibernate Dialect: MARIADB103
Using Internal Container for testing vs. Tomcat

The key error is Hibernate Could not instantiate id generator, here is the console log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-04-26 13:53:52.895  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.c.ContractPlusApplication            : Starting ContractPlusApplication on mark-Inspiron-5759 with PID 23238 (/home/mark/eclipse-workspace/contract-plus.zip_expanded/contract-plus/target/classes started by mark in /home/mark/eclipse-workspace/contract-plus.zip_expanded/contract-plus)
2020-04-26 13:53:52.897  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.c.ContractPlusApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-26 13:53:52.939  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/mark/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/mark/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/home/mark/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/home/mark/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/home/mark/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/home/mark/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/home/mark/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2020-04-26 13:53:52.939  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-04-26 13:53:52.939  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-04-26 13:53:53.535  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-26 13:53:53.584  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 43ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-04-26 13:53:54.033  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-26 13:53:54.040  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-26 13:53:54.040  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-04-26 13:53:54.042  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : An older version [1.2.21] of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat recommends a minimum version of [1.2.23]
2020-04-26 13:53:54.042  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.21] using APR version [1.6.3].
2020-04-26 13:53:54.042  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2020-04-26 13:53:54.042  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2020-04-26 13:53:54.045  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018]
2020-04-26 13:53:54.087  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-26 13:53:54.088  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1149 ms
2020-04-26 13:53:54.190  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-26 13:53:54.225  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-04-26 13:53:54.258  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-04-26 13:53:54.305  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-04-26 13:53:54.450  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-04-26 13:53:54.515  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
2020-04-26 13:53:54.711  WARN 23238 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.mmurphy.contractplus.core.entities.Client]
2020-04-26 13:53:54.712  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-04-26 13:53:54.714  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-04-26 13:53:54.716  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-04-26 13:53:54.726  INFO 23238 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-26 13:53:54.735 ERROR 23238 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.mmurphy.contractplus.core.entities.Client]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.mmurphy.contractplus.ContractPlusApplication.main(ContractPlusApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.mmurphy.contractplus.core.entities.Client]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.mmurphy.contractplus.core.entities.Client]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.lambda$new$1(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1628) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:285) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [client_sequence] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.configure(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Here is my entity

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;

import lombok.Data;


@Data
@Entity(name="clients")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="client_generator", sequenceName="client_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="client_generator")
    private long id;

    private String client_name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ClientStatus status;

    @CreatedDate 
    private Timestamp created_date;

    @LastModifiedDate 
    private Timestamp change_date;

    private Timestamp hold_date;

    private Timestamp deleted_date;

}
```

The obvious duplicates that say Maria does not support sequences are out of date as one of the stated changes for the MariaDB103 dialect is sequence support.

I also saw some similar questions asking about custom generators, but I was not able to glean the issue from them. I was able to make it work using IDENTITY and auto numbering, but I wanted to try the SEQUENCE, but can't figure out the secret incantation. What is missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hibernate 5.4 tries to validate the `allocationSize` of the `@SequenceGenerator` by the database sequence increment size.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [client_sequence] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].
```

You should correct your mapping in the following way:

```java
@Data
@Entity(name="clients")
public class Client {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name="client_generator", sequenceName="client_sequence", allocationSize=1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="client_generator")
  private long id;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Is this true even if the default allocation size is not 1?

Comment: The default value of `allocationSize` is 50, but your db sequence looks like defined somehow like this `CREATE SEQUENCE client_sequence START WITH ... INCREMENT BY 1;`

Comment: hibernate validates that `allocationSize` has the same value as `INCREMENT BY ...`  that is why you get this error

Comment: The next thing that is odd is that it seams to work fine if I leave off the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation, or if the generator attribute on `@GeneratedValue` does not match the name attribute of `@SequenceGenerator`. Or if everything matches and I use allocationSize=1. I have only tried listing values, not writing new though. So that might blow up. Very odd.